# Error type 3. Activity class {com.awesome_project/ com.awesome_project.MainActivity} does not exist in react native (Android device)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've created the project using the following command.

```
react-native init Awesome_Project
```

I've started the packager using the following command.

```
react-native start
```

I've connected my Android mobile using USB drive.

I've opened another command prompt and run the following adb command to make sure that only one device is connected.

```
adb devices
```

I've started the application using the following command.

```
react-native run-android
```

I've been confronted with the following error.

```
open: Permission denied
open: Permission denied
Starting: Intent { com.awesome_project/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.awesome_project/ com.awesome_project.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Comment: in my case i just uninstall application and reinstall using cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android

Answer (score 147):

Make sure `android/app/build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "WHATEVER_THIS_IS" 
}
```

needs to match `android/app/src/main/java/com/app_name/MainActivity.java` line one:

```
package WHATEVER_THIS_IS;
```

needs to match `android/app/src/main/java/com/app_name/MainApplication.java` line one:

```
package WHATEVER_THIS_IS;
```

needs to match `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` line one:

```
package="WHATEVER_THIS_IS">
```

Comment: added `android>app>src>main>java>com>app_name>MainApplication.java` direction too.

Comment: If your `Activity class {} does not exist` you will lose on enhanced features like deep-linking.  It's pretty important that the device know how to launch the app without you pressing the button.  Just good developer practice...

Comment: I've done checking all this, and didn't solve anything

Comment: This didn't solve my problem either, but @Fran solution of `adb uninstall WHATEVER_THIS_IS` did solve it!

Comment: This worked, but failed a couple of times at the outset because I had a typo in one of the app ID locations specified or forgot to run `gradelew clean` between edits, an important step. For whatever reason our app needs a different `applicationId` in `app/src/build.gradle` in order to separate builds for Microsoft AppCenter Code push. Switching it to match the other files allowed me to run the build on a local emulator.

Comment: Its bonkers that actual folder structure of MainActivity has to match applicationId  because you may want to load different activity as launcher which could be in different package then how ?

Comment: Most of this answer is wrong. 1) Android starts the Activity defined in the manifest so MainActivity.java can be anywhere as long as the definition in the manifest has the correct reference. 2) The same is true for the Application class. Name and package can be whatever, just the manifest needs to reference it correctly. 3) the package declaration in the manifest has nothing to do with what activity is started. All it does is define the namespace for the R file and it's also used to resolve relative path references (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#package)

Answer (score 119):

I uninstalled the app from my device and was not able to see it in my Settings > Apps at all. The error finally went away after I fully uninstalled the app by doing:

```
adb uninstall com.appname
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a work profile (in additional to a personal profile) on my Android and had uninstalled it from one but not the other.

Comment: Solved my problem!

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: My god. Lucky I found this. Why is the error message so misleading?

Comment: @Fran dude you are the saviour.. i owe you.. Thanks buddy.

Comment: You saved my lot of time... Thanks

Comment: you have saved us all!! Thank you

Comment: In my case, I uninstalled the app directly on my phone then issue arise. Uninstalling the app using adb (`adb unistall <appId>`) solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! After going through a lot of answers this finally worked.

Answer (score 40):

If you have appIdSuffix you should add it to the command for react native run command.

```
eg.   react-native run-android --appIdSuffix beta
```

Should add shortcut to package.json and run via npm.

```
...
"scripts": {
 ...
  "android-beta": "react-native run-android --appIdSuffix beta",
},
```

Then just run:

```
npm run android-beta
```

Comment: you saved me from a minor headache

Comment: just adding: where to find what suffix you need to add ... look for `applicationIdSuffix` in file `build.gradle` ... it could be defined in `buildTypes` or flavour  like this: `buildTypes { debug { applicationIdSuffix ".debug" ...`

Answer (score 20):

**adb uninstall packageName**
 Worked for me.
for eg: **adb uninstall com.abc**

Comment: Just few days back I upvoted this and now had to come back here one more time. Really helpful.

Comment: what is the packageName? How can I find it?

Answer (score 14):

In my case the **app just doesn't open automatically**, there's no other issue.

Just search for the app icon in your android device (look at location of all applications) and tap on it to **open the app manually**. The packager will begin to load the app as usual.

So this seems to be a bug here. Unfortunately I don't really know what's causing it.

Comment: Although you are correct in that the app doesn't launch automatically, you WANT the auto launching.  Without this you lose enhanced features like deep-linking.  See my answer above, your configuration is off somewhere.

Comment: set path of sdk in environment variable ,
That's it !!

Comment: i had the same experience, the apk is intalled but the emulator just dosent start the app automatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289591/react-native-productflavors-error-type-3-activity-class-does-not-exist

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49916711/7313872

Answer (score 12):

I had changed my application id from `com.appName` to `com.companyName.appName`, and I had made this update in `android>app>build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.companyName.appName" // was previously "com.appName"
}
```

I also changed my file structure from `android>app>src>main>java>com>appName` to `android>app>src>main>java>com>companyName>appName`. This is when I got the error.

**To fix the error**, I simply did a project wide search (`CMD-SHIFT-F` in Atom) for `com.appName`, and replaced them all with `com.companyName.appName`. Problem solved!

Comment: thanks. I think that it cause by using Refactor feature with Android Studio. 

Maybe I had run rename or move somemthing... 

But it doesn't change relative to react-native.

Answer (score 9):

try running adb command to install the apk (should provide more output) from android dir in your project: `adb install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`

In my case was a insufficient storage case

[facebook/react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native) issue [#2885](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2885#issuecomment-142038885)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue after having a successful build installed on my phone, but long story short I had to uninstall it in order to do a fresh install. After uninstalling the app and trying to do a `react-native run-android`, I received this error.

Seems that 'uninstalling' an application on some devices only disables it in case you wish to undo the uninstall within a certain time frame. To remedy this, I went into Applications under settings and selected my app and completely uninstalled it. After that I was able to successfully build my app again. Hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 5):

You may have deleted/uninstalled your app, but when you check in your settings/apps, you can see that it's not totally uninstalled.

- Go to Settings.
- Go to Apps.
- Select your app. (here, you can verify that your app is not uninstalled properly).
- Open the overflow menu on the top right and select Uninstall for all users.
  Done. Try to install then launch your app again.

---

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14952#issuecomment-364853973)

Comment: It worked for me, somehow i had it installed for not the current user...

Answer (score 5):

When working with react-native-config, I ran into this issue when using `applicationIdSuffix` with `productFlavors`.

adding `--appIdSuffix=[YOUR_FLAVOR]` to my `react-native run-android` commands did the job.
e.g

```java
...
    flavorDimensions "env"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "[DEV] My App"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
        staging {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "[STG] My App"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }
        prod {
            resValue "string", "app_name", "My App"
        }
    }
...
```

```json
...
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android --variant=devDebug --appIdSuffix=dev",
    "android:staging": "react-native run-android --variant=stagingDebug --appIdSuffix=staging",
    "android:prod": "react-native run-android --variant=prodDebug",
    "android:staging:release": "react-native run-android --variant=stagingRelease --appIdSuffix=staging",
    "android:prod:release": "react-native run-android --variant=prodRelease",
},
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I've had the issue for long time and only with your method it solved

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 38s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "a77c634"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.helloworld/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.helloworld/com.helloworld.MainActivity} does not exist.e
```

For me, my target device had multiple accounts, so before running the app for another ime, make sure you uninstall it from all accounts.

Answer (score 3):

I had a slightly different take on the same issue.

I'm not using react, however I did run into this same issue.

I tried all of the solutions on this page and, oddly enough, each of them worked once.  But the problem continued to come back.

In the end I found that doing:

1. adb uninstall com.appname
2. followed by a restart of the handset

Solved the issue every time since discovering.

Using a Samsung S8 and Android  3.4.1.  No crazy libraries other than OKHttp.  Running on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else running into this issue where there are no solutions, if you've linked libraries, make sure that in the `settings.gradle` file located in `ProjectName/android` has your app in the include statement, like so: `include ':ThirdPartyLibrary', ':app'`. I forgot `:app` and it was build and installing the 3rd party library, but not the actual app, resulting in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening if you have enabled build varaints in your app build.gradle file.

When react-native runs, it seems to prefix test or something to your application id which changes the package names in some files but leaves others the same. Your application cannot find .MainActivity because it actually does not exist in the new package namespace that was generated.

Here are some things to try to fix this issue:

- Use FQDN in your Manifest file for the names of the application class and the activity class.
- Replace your android cli file with this [one](https://github.com/kgritesh/react-native/blob/34f5f6a09ae0ebe3f00f028ac1d3e2127b38f5fd/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js). This is the file in `/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid`

This should solve your issue.

Comment: I think you are right, but I don't know how to fix it. Android studio seems to automatically be adding a .debug to the end of my package name. The Build Variants tab has 'debug' and 'release' as options, but seemingly no way to remove them. Further, the information in the docs https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html seems lacking in this regard.

Comment: I am currently working on a project where I will need to support build variants before deployment. I will endeavour to sort this issue out and update the answer with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurred in my case when I uninstalled the app and tried installing with `react-native run-android` again.
Following worked for me:
1. Go to Application List from Settings Menu.
2. You will see your application in the list with a message on the left side *"App not installed for this user"*.
3. Open that app in the settings, and then click on the top-right menu icon and select *"Uninstall for all users"*.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

make sure your applicationid in gradle and package name is same

Comment: this was the problem for me, using hyphen char breaks the package :d

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get this error because you don't uninstall another previous version of the app, on the LG phones you must go to app's on settings and uninstall the app, this happens to me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case.. none of the above solution worked.
Then, i found the cause of it, i had previously installed application with same package name. I had uninstalled it from my phone, but as i have Oreo device.. it was installed in another user also. So, by uninstalling from all users.. solved my issue.
It might not be helpful in your case.. but still this is my workaround.

Comment: A number of people already mentioned that they uninstalled the app first.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing the debug application manually on the mobile phone.

To do so, go to **[Project_Path]\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk**

Copy this **app-debug.apk** to your mobile device.

Now, just install it normally in your mobile and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Huawei p20 lite.
Tried to install app from downloads which would not install. Went back to run to install in android studio and got the error 
error 3 mainactivity does not exist.
 Had to delete user 'private space ' 
to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

> cd android

and then

> ./gradlew uA

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This happens when we uninstall apk from mobile manually.It shows MainActivity does not exist.
Solution: Go to apps in setting and uninstall the instance of App for all users and run again using react-native run-android will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers posted above, no any outcome for my use case.

It got resolved finally by executing like this:

`react-native run-android --variant=alphaDebug`

if there are multiple flavours in the app, then we must mention variant 
through command line

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the wrong package_name (`client.client_info.android_client_info.package_name`) in google-services.json (from Firebase). It had to match those four values as @parker mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after changing my project package name.
I tried some of the other answers here but nothing worked until I manually deleted the `android/build` directory, and re-ran `react-native run-android` forcing the app to be rebuilt from src.
Turns out the build was cached including references to the old package name.

Answer (score 0):

**One that worked for me. Works in case if you accidentally uninstalled app from the connected device**

1. Delete apk: `sudo rm -rf android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug`
2. Then: `sudo npm run android`

Answer (score 0):

**adb uninstall com.packagename**. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused too if you're downloading a yarn based application and using npm install instead of yarn install to get your dependencies.
So try to redownload the project and use the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

for me removing the applicationId worked.

```
 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.companyName.xyz" // remove or comment out this line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The adb uninstall command did it for me too. On Windows this is the command I had to execute:

```
%USERPROFILE%\appdata\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb uninstall org.company.topic
```