# Change package name for Android in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I used `react-native init MyApp` to initialise a new React Native app.
This created among others an Android project with the package `com.myapp`.

What's the best way to change this package name, for example to: `com.mycompany.myapp`?

I tried changing it in `AndroidManifest.xml` but it created other errors, so I'm assuming it's not the way.

Any idea?

Comment: Left click on package name and go for Refactor--> Rename option to rename package name.

Comment: What works best for me now is just find & replace

Comment: You can also try this https://saumya.github.io/ray/articles/72/

Comment: for me search & replace worked

Comment: The pragmatic approach: 1- `npx react-native init MycompanyMyapp`, 2- Change **only** the `applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"` in `android/app/build.gradle`. "However, the application ID and package name are independent of each other" – https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Answer (score 647, accepted):

I've renamed the project' subfolder from: "*android/app/src/main/java/MY/APP/**OLD_ID**/*" to: "*android/app/src/main/java/MY/APP/**NEW_ID**/*"

Then manually switched the old and new package ids:

In:
*android/app/src/main/java/MY/APP/NEW_ID/MainActivity.java*:

```
package MY.APP.NEW_ID;
```

In *android/app/src/main/java/MY/APP/NEW_ID/MainApplication.java*:

```
package MY.APP.NEW_ID;
```

In *android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
package="MY.APP.NEW_ID"
```

And in *android/app/build.gradle*:

```
applicationId "MY.APP.NEW_ID"
```

In *android/app/BUCK*:

```
android_build_config(
  package="MY.APP.NEW_ID"
)
android_resource(
  package="MY.APP.NEW_ID"
)
```

Gradle' cleaning in the end (in */android* folder):

```
./gradlew clean
```

Comment: I also need to edit file BUCK to replace old package value with the new one. BTW, the 2 files MainAcitivity.java and MainApplication.java should be relocated to the new physical path.

Comment: I also renamed the directory `android/app/src/main/java/com/old_app_name/` to `...com/new_app_name/` and it seems to work.

Comment: I had error "Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE" until I manually forced cleaning of the android device simulator: adb uninstall my.package.name ... So directions are fine, but android simulator can "hold on" to old info in a bad way that makes it look like directions don't work. (And simply uninstalling the app did NOT fix this!)

Comment: I was reading about this and I tried this library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename

seems to be working pretty fine for this, it does not only rename the app but it also can change the bundle identifier

Comment: don't forget to change `applicationId` in `app/build.gradle` too

Comment: What about `android/settings.gradle` file? (specifically `rootProject.name = 'OLD_ID'`)

Comment: Uh, oh and `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` and `app_name` inside that file.

Comment: bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory  i am getting this.

Comment: do it in *android/* folder @Anuj

Comment: @Cherniv how did you get to have "MY.APP.OLD_ID" package name. I mean react native creates "MY.APP"? I'm trying to achieve 3 level package name

Comment: i was need to delete the old path and conetent then it worked

Comment: these instructions worked as a first step. However I also had to sync with gradle in Android Studio project again, or I would get errors at build time.

Comment: don't forget the Proguard rules, if any

Comment: The answer was great and helpful. It would be nice bonus to have also info about iOS package name changes.

Comment: I also had to rename the import file of BasePackageList in `MainApplication` and in `android/app/src/main/generated/BasePackageList.java`

Comment: For RN 0.60+, there's another LoC that has to be changed in `MainApplication#initializeFlipper`:

`Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("MY.APP.NEW_ID");`

Comment: it's helpful to do a project wide search () for com.appName and replace them all with com.companyName.appName. And if you do it with VScode, remember to disable "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files".

Comment: if you are using **firebase** then you also need to replace old package value in two instances of `package_name` in `google-services.json`

Comment: and change app.json file too

Answer (score 106):

I use the [react-native-rename*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) npm package. Install it via

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

Then, from the root of your React Native project, execute the following:

```
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```

Comment: thats simple and tricky one, I just need to update the MainApplication.java manually.

Comment: Thanks, broke the project

Comment: @AkashRajput  did you fix your issue? please let us know if you found any solution

Comment: @SaleemKhan Had to create the project again. This time with react-native init.. Just copy the files.

Comment: thanks @AkashRajput :) but I was referring to the renaming issue. Did you figure out a way to do it?

Comment: @SaleemKhan in iOS just change the bundle ID & in Android Studio do manual refactoring reference: https://saumya.github.io/ray/articles/72/

Comment: It broke my project, and had to create a new project :(

Comment: @AchaBill This answer is from 2017 things have changed since... be careful out there.

Comment: Worked like a charm in "react-native": "0.63.4", Thanks for saving my time. :)

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure you create a git branch just in case: `git checkout -b newBranchName`

Comment: for me this worked for android but crashed for ios, i just undid all ios changes updated in xcode manually

Answer (score 45):

To change the package name from `com.myapp` to: `com.mycompany.myapp` (for example),

1. For iOS app of the react app, use xcode - under general.
2. For the android app, open the build.gradle at module level. The one in the `android/app` folder. You will find

```
// ...
defaultConfig {
     applicationId com.myapp
     // ...
}
// ...
```

Change the `com.myapp` to whatever you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the easiest way to change your package name. Tho, not changing your local package name, this will change your next build package. Thanks! After doing this, do `./gradlew clean` and then `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`.

Comment: "However, the `applicationId` and the local `package` name are independent of each other", "`applicationId` uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store" – https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

Comment: not work for me ```No matching client found for package name 'xxxxx'```

Comment: For changing the package name of android, I ran into this error and fixed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131769/error-type-3-activity-class-com-awesome-project-com-awesome-project-mainactiv

Comment: Finally, this is the only way that worked for me. I needed to change just the .aab package id for play store upload, and this accomplished just that.

Answer (score 19):

you can simply use react-native-rename npm package.

Install using

`npm install react-native-rename -g`

Then from the root of your React Native project execute the following

`react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp`

`react-native-rename on npm`

but notice that, this lib remove your `MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java`.
before changing your package name, give a backup from this two file and, after changing package name just put it back to their place. this solution work for me

more info:
[react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)

Comment: No effect if you don't change app name "Please try a different name."

Comment: actually, I try different name for my project. but when I change my project name react-native-rename removes that two files from my project.

Answer (score 11):

### REACT 0.64 | 2021 NO EXPO

Let original App name be: `com.myApp`
Let New App Name: 'com.newname.myApp`

1. `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`

---

Rename xml attribute: `package="com.newname.myApp"

---

2. `android\app\src\main\java\com\[yourAppName]\MainActivity.java`

Rename first line from `package com.myApp;` To `package com.newname.myApp;`

---

3. `android\app\src\main\java\com\[yourAppName]\MainApplication.java`

Rename first line  To `package com.newname.myApp;`

In class `private static void initializeFlipper`
reneme this line:

`Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.myApp.ReactNativeFlipper");`

To

`Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.newname.myApp.ReactNativeFlipper");`

---

4. `android\app\build.gradle`

On the `defaultConfig` rename `applicationId`

to "com.newname.myApp"

---

5. Run on command line:

   ```
     $ npx react-native start
     $ npx react-native run-android
   ```

Comment: Check google-services.json if you have one too.

Answer (score 10):

Goto Android studio

Right click your package (most probably com)-> Refractor -> Rename -> Enter new package name in the dialog -> Do Refractor

It will rename your package name everywhere.

Comment: It will not affect in the whole project structure i guess.

Comment: How can do with React-Native JS project ?

Answer (score 10):

In VS Code, press `Ctrl + Shift + F` and enter your old package name in 'Find' and enter your new package in 'Replace'. Then press 'Replace all occurrences'.

Definitely not the pragmatic way. But, it's done the trick for me.

Comment: This worked fine on a Mac.. In my case, I have a RN project on iOS and Android. I just needed to make sure that I didn't make any changes to iOS proj.

Comment: Might also want to search/replace com/you/package mappings along with com.your.package.

Comment: This isn't enough (well, maybe it is, if you're using Expo). You also have to rename the folders under `android/app/src/main/java` and `android/app/src/debug/java`. The folder structure is e.g. `com/acme/awesomeapp`, and reflects the package name structure.

Comment: @ChristianDavén +1
I'd just like to add that I had an unpublished app with the package name, say, `com.myApp` & then I replaced all instances of it with `com.myNewApp` and nothing broke. It would be prudent to rename the folders as you suggest, but that's not a hard requirement. Should you rename? Yes. Do you have to? No.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Android Studio-

changing `com.myapp` to `com.mycompany.myapp`

1. create a new package hierarchy com.mycompany.myapp under `android/app/src/main/java`
2. Copy all classes from `com.myapp` to `com.mycompany.myapp` using Android studio GUI
3. Android studio will take care of putting suitable package name for all copied classes. This is useful if you have some custom modules and don't want to manually replace in all the .java files.
4. Update `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and `android/app/build.gradle` (replace `com.myapp` to `com.mycompany.myapp`
5. Sync the project (gradle build)

Answer (score 9):

The init script generates a unique identifier for Android based on the name you gave it (e.g. `com.acmeapp` for `AcmeApp`).

You can see what name was generated by looking for the applicationId key in `android/app/build.gradle`.

If you need to change that unique identifier, do it now as described below:

In the `/android` folder, replace all occurrences of `com.acmeapp` by `com.acme.app`

Then change the directory structure with the following commands:

`mkdir android/app/src/main/java/com/acme`

`mv android/app/src/main/java/com/acmeapp android/app/src/main/java/com/acme/app`

You need a folder level for each dot in the app identifier.

Source: https://blog.elao.com/en/dev/from-react-native-init-to-app-stores-real-quick/

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `VSCode` and `Windows`.

1.Press `Control + Shift + F`.

2.Find Your `Package Name` and `Replace All` with your `new Package Name`.

3. type `"cd android"`
4. type `"./gradlew clean"`

Comment: Seems like a bad approach but worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 6):

I have a solution based on @Cherniv's answer (works on macOS for me). Two differences: I have a Main2Activity.java in the java folder that I do the same thing to, and I don't bother calling ./gradlew clean since it seems like the react-native packager does that automatically anyways.

Anyways, my solution does what Cherniv's does, except I made a bash shell script for it since I'm building multiple apps using one set of code and want to be able to easily change the package name whenever I run my npm scripts.

Here is the bash script I used. You'll need to modify the packageName you want to use, and add anything else you want to it... but here are the basics. You can create a .sh file, give permission, and then run it from the same folder you run react-native from:

```
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/java


mkdir -p ./android/app/src/main/java/com/MyWebsite/MyAppName
    packageName="com.MyWebsite.MyAppName"
    sed -i '' -e "s/.*package.*/package "$packageName";/" ./android/app/src/main/javaFiles/Main2Activity.java
    sed -i '' -e "s/.*package.*/package "$packageName";/" ./android/app/src/main/javaFiles/MainActivity.java
    sed -i '' -e "s/.*package.*/package "$packageName";/" ./android/app/src/main/javaFiles/MainApplication.java
    sed -i '' -e "s/.*package=\".*/    package=\""$packageName"\"/" ./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
    sed -i '' -e "s/.*package = '.*/  package = '"$packageName"',/" ./android/app/BUCK
    sed -i '' -e "s/.*applicationId.*/    applicationId \""$packageName"\"/" ./android/app/build.gradle

    cp -R ./android/app/src/main/javaFiles/ ./android/app/src/main/java/com/MyWebsite/MyAppName
```

DISCLAIMER: You'll need to edit MainApplication.java's comment near the bottom of the java file first. It has the word 'package' in the comment. Because of how the script works, it takes any line with the word 'package' in it and replaces it. Because of this, this script may not be future proofed as there might be that same word used somewhere else.

Second Disclaimer: the first 3 sed commands edit the java files from a directory called javaFiles. I created this directory myself since I want to have one set of java files that are copied from there (as I might add new packages to it in the future). You will probably want to do the same thing. So copy all the files from the java folder (go through its subfolders to find the actual java files) and put them in a new folder called javaFiles.

Third Disclaimer: You'll need to edit the packageName variable to be in line with the paths at the top of the script and bottom (com.MyWebsite.MyAppName to com/MyWebsite/MyAppName)

Answer (score 6):

**To change the Package name you have to edit four files in your project :**

```
 1. android/app/src/main/java/com/reactNativeSampleApp/MainActivity.java
 2. android/app/src/main/java/com/reactNativeSampleApp/MainApplication.java
 3. android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
 4. android/app/build.gradle
```

**The first 2 files have the package name as something like below.**

```
 package com.WHATEVER_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_IS;
```

**Change it to your desired package name.**

```
 package com.YOUR_DESIRED_PACKAGE_NAME;
```

**You have to also edit the package name in 2 other files.**

```
  android/app/build.gradle

  android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

**Note if you have a google-services.json file in your project then you have to also change your package name in that file.**

After this, you have to ./gradlew clean your project.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of bad answers here

if you want to change the package name, go to your build.gradle in app

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your.new.package.name" //change this line
```

then when running the app from the command line, pass in the new package name as an arg

```
react-native run-android --appId your.new.package.name
```

There's no need to rename your whole project

Comment: What about ios? @MobileMon

Comment: for iOS just change bundle identifier in xcode

Answer (score 5):

In case, you are fine with creating new react-native project, and migrate your code there, you can simply do it using:

```
npx react-native init --package-name com.yourcompany.yourapp yourappname
```

, which will also setup the required and respective nested folder structure based on your custom package name. Then you can proceed with migrating your code there. It has worked in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Android Studio, open app, right click on java and choose 
New and then Package.

Give the name you want (e.g. com.something).

Move the files from the other package (you want to rename) to the new Package. Delete the old package.

Go to your project in your editor and use the shortcut for searching in all the files (on mac is shift cmd F). Type in the name of your old package. Change all the references to the new package name.

Go to Android Studio, Build, Clean Project, Rebuild Project.

Done!

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

After running this:

```sh
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```

Make sure to also goto `Build.gradle` under `android/app/...`
and rename the application Id as shown below:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId:com.appname.xxx
........
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*I will provide you step by step procedure.*

*First of all, we need to understand why we need to rename a package?
Mostly for uniquely identifying App right? So React Native is a cross-platform to develop an app that runs on both iOS and Android. So What I recommended is to need the same identifier in both the platforms. In case *Android* **Package Name** is a unique identifier of your App and for **iOS** its **bundle ID**.*

Steps:

1. Firstly close all editors/studio eg:  xcode android studio vscode and then Install package "react-native-rename" in the terminal by running the command (*Keep your project folder copy in another folder for backup if you don't feel this safe*):

> npm install react-native-rename -g

2. After sucessfully installing package open your project folder in the terminal and hit the below command where "Your app name Within double quotes" is app name and  <Your Package Name without double/single quotes> is replaced with package/bundle name/id:

> react-native-rename "< Your app name Within double quotes >" -b <Your Package Name without double/single quotes>

Example: react-native-rename "Aptitude Test App" -b com.vaibhavmojidra.aptitudetestapp

**Note** Make sure the package/bundle name/id is all in small case

3. This is not yet done yet now every file will change where the it had bundle/package names except one in ios project which we manually need to do for that open the **xcode>open a project or file> choose file from projectfolder/ios/projectname.xcodeproj** and **click open**
4. Click on your projectname.xcodeproj that is first file in the **project navigator** then in **field of Bundle identifier** enter the package name/Bundle ID as below:

[image]

5. After that run in the terminal

> cd ios

6. Then run

> pod install

7. Then run

> cd ..

8. Now you are done for all the changes for ios just last step is to open Android Studio>Open an Existing Project> select projectfolder/android folder > Click on open
9. Let it load and complete all the process and then in the **Build** Menu click "**Clean Project**" and the in **File Menu > Close Project**
10. Close All editors and Now You can try the commands to run project on ios and android it will run with renamed packaged just while start server add extra flag --reset-cache:

> npm start --reset-cache

***Enjoy it will work now***

Comment: this is just the best answer for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by manually updating package name in following places

```
1) app.json               |  ./
2) index.js               |  ./
3) package.json           |  ./
4) settings.gradle        |  ./android/
5) BUCK                   |  ./android/app/
6) build.gradle           |  ./android/app/
7) AndroidManifest.xml    |  ./android/app/src/main/
8) MainActivity.java      |  ./android/app/src/main/java/**
9) MainApplication.java   |  ./android/app/src/main/java/**
10)strings.xml            |  ./android/app/src/main/res/values
11)ReactNativeFlipper.java|  ./android/app/src/debug/java/com/<package-name>/
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the react-native-rename* npm package. Install it via

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

Then, from the root of your React Native project, execute the following:

```
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

For those coming from **RN 0.72+**.

Do what the top answers tells you to do and...

**Please** double check this `android/app/build.gradle`

```
// namespace needs to be the same as the top package import in MainApplication.java
    namespace "com.myapp"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.domain"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple you just install npm library for same

```
npm i react-native-rename
```

Use the link for follow steps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename

NOTE: DON'T FORGET TO RUN BELOW COMMANDS AFTER FINISH YOUR WORK:

```
watchman watch-del-all
npm start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple way :

```
cd /your/project/dir
```

run this command :

```
grep -rl "com.your.app" . | xargs sed -i 's/com.your.app/com.yournew.newapp/g'
```

rename your folder

```
android/app/src/main/java/com/your/app
```

change to

```
android/app/src/main/java/com/yournew/newapp
```

Answer (score 0):

After renaming package name everywhere,
from android studio. File -> Invalidate caches/Restart may fix this type of errors

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This information can be helpful for you so listen properly...

```
After updating package name and changing files, don't forget to change in 
package.json and app.json file at the root directory of your react native project
```

Otherwise you will get this error below

```
Invariant Violation: "Your new package name" has not been registered
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Chernykh's answer is correct for `react-native` 0.67 and below
For `react-native` 0.68 and above with the new architecture once you're down with the steps which Ivan Chernykh has mentioned

For `android` you have to go to `app` => `src` => `main` => `jni` folder

In `MainApplicationTurboModuleManagerDelegate.h`

change below line

```
static constexpr auto kJavaDescriptor =
      "Lcom/yournewpackagename/newarchitecture/modules/MainApplicationTurboModuleManagerDelegate;";
```

In `MainComponentsRegistry.h`

```
 constexpr static auto kJavaDescriptor =
      "Lcom/yournewpackagename/newarchitecture/components/MainComponentsRegistry;";
```

Comment: Works, But it requires addition steps..
You also needs to change the "com.app" in each file inside "newarchitecture" folder

Answer (score 0):

I just learned this today but adding this answer to help others. You just need to add a `namespace` to the `app/build.gradle` that references the old name, like this:

```
defaultConfig {
  applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
  namespace "com.myapp"
}
```

Then you can have a bash script that changes the `applicationId` with something like this:

```bash
function sedi {
  if [ "$(uname)" == "Linux" ]; then
    \sed -i "$@"
  else
    \sed -i "" "$@"
  fi
}

bundle_name=com.mycompany.myapp

sedi -E "s/applicationId \"[-0-9a-zA-Z._]*\"/applicationId \"${bundle_name}\"/" android/app/build.gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native@0.70.x
Tried to rename package name from `com.x` to `com.y.z`

I got through this painful process by doing these:

1. Change `displayName` in `app.json` to `z`.

```json
{
  "name": "<THIS_SHOULD_STAY_SAME>",
  "displayName": "<Z>"
}
```

2. Change the content of the string `app_name` in `strings.xml`

```xml
<resources>
  ...
  <string name="app_name"><Z></string>
  ...
</resources>
```

3. Search through your react-native project for `com.x` and replace all `com.x` with `com.y.z`

> !important: In case you're using external services, and in case if
> you're generated a file and put it under `/android` you may want to
> make sure the services that you're using will still work. I recommend
> you to generate a new config file(s) using your new package name
> `com.y.z` and put it after the finishing the steps described below.

4. Update the folder structure to this:

```
old: .../android/app/src/main/java/com/x
new: .../android/app/src/main/java/com/y/z
```

5. Move all the files under `.../android/app/src/main/java/com/x` to `.../android/app/src/main/java/com/y/z`.
6. Clean up.

```bash
  $ ./gradlew clean
```

7. Build.

```bash
  $ react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I need to change the package `com.yourProjectName` to `boonagency.connachttribune`

[image]

So then I just do that:-

1. `yourApp/android/app/build.gradle`

   ```
     defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.connachtapp"
     minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
     targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
   ```

to

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "boonagency.connachttribune"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

[image]

2. `yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.connachtapp">
   ```

to

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="boonagency.connachttribune">
```

3. change folder name

   ```
   yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/java/com/connachtapp
   ```

   to

   ```
    yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/java/boonagency/connachtapp
   ```
4. `yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/java/boonagency/connachtapp/MainApplication.java`

   ```
   package boonagency.connachttribune; // change here
   ...
   import boonagency.connachttribune.newarchitecture.MainApplicationReactNativeHost; // change here
   ...
    Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("boonagency.connachttribune.ReactNativeFlipper"); // change here
   ```
5. `yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/java/boonagency/connachtapp/MainActivity.java`

   ```
   package boonagency.connachttribune; // change here
   ```
6. `yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/java/boonagency/connachtapp/newarchitecture/MainApplicationReactNativeHost.java`

[image]

7. `yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/java/boonagency/connachtapp/newarchitecture/modules/MainApplicationTurboModuleManagerDelegate.java`

   ```
   package boonagency.connachttribune.newarchitecture.modules; // change here
   ```
8. `yourProjectName/android/app/src/main/java/boonagency/connachtapp/newarchitecture/components/MainComponentsRegistry.java`

   ```
   package boonagency.connachttribune.newarchitecture.components; // change here
   ```
9. last just run

   ```
   cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && npm run android
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to rename a react native project
But, I recommend a package named react-native-rename.
It take care all the renaming procedures without any issues

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename

Answer (score -3):

Go to file ***android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*** -

Update :

attr **android:label** of Element **application** as :

> Old value - *android:label="@string/app_name"*
>
> New Value - *android:label="(string you want to put)"*

and

attr **android:label** of Element **activity** as :

> Old value - *android:label="@string/app_name"*
>
> New Value - *android:label="(string you want to put)"*

Worked for me, hopefully it will help.

Comment: I honestly don't think this answer should've been downvoted as much as it has been. However, this answer _does_ **not** address what was asked in the question - how to change **the package name**. Yet, it answers the question "how to change the title of of the app that appears in the launcher". Is it a relevant answer? Not really. Does it contain useful information? Yes. Therefore, I suggest you find a question which asks about the launcher title and post your solution _there_ instead of here.