# How to change application namespace on React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I would like to use "a.custom.namespace.projectname" instead of "com.projectname". Is it possible?

Comment: is this relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native/37390022 ?

Comment: I will try this method.. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390022/448292), but I would recommend you to do it using **[react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)** npm package, like this:

Install it:

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

On you project root:

```
react-native-rename "Your New Name" -b com.mynewcompany.mynewapp
```

It will rename some folders and files, and change many strings on your android and ios folders.

When finished, if you want, you can remove the package:

```
npm uninstall react-native-rename
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual Studio Code:

1. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> ( or <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on a Mac).

2.Find your package name and Replace All with your new package name.

- Type `cd android`
- type `./gradlew clean`