# Changing the package name in a react-native app

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I've created an app in react-native. I need the package name to be:
com.org.appname

React-native does not allow you to specify this as the package name in the init, or to change it after init.

```
react-native init --package="com.org.appname"
```

does not work

Changing the package name as described in [Change package name for Android in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native) also doesn't work and results in the following error on react-native run-android

Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Answer (score 19):

in iOS project you just need to change **BundleID** with Xcode.

In Android project you need to change **package** name in 4 files:

```
android/app/src/main/java/com/reactNativeSampleApp/MainActivity.java
android/app/src/main/java/com/reactNativeSampleApp/MainApplication.java
android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
android/app/build.gradle
```

**good practice is also to modify BUCK file** in Android project, in two places, and correspondingly adjust hierarchy in android project, although it is not necessary:

**BUCK** file:

```
 android_build_config(
     name = "build_config",
     package = "app.new.name",
 )

 android_resource(
     name = "res",
     package = "app.new.name",
     res = "src/main/res",
 )
```

run command
    `./gradlew clean`

Comment: Is there an update to this? Currently only changing the BundleID with Xcode did not work with RN 0.61.

Answer (score 8):

According to this https://saumya.github.io/ray/articles/72/, you can run this command from the start

```
react-native init MyAwesomeProject -package "com.example.app"
```

But if you already generated your app via

```
react-native init MyAwesomeProject
```

You can modify app name in file

```
android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
```

Then you can modify package name in files

```
android/app/src/main/java/com/reactNativeSampleApp/MainActivity.java
android/app/src/main/java/com/reactNativeSampleApp/MainApplication.java
android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml ( optional as per my experience )
android/app/build.gradle
```

Lastly,  run the following commands (from inside the app's android/ directory)

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

**To change iOS version package name, use Xcode**

Comment: where is this stuff documented? even just the cli options? crazy that so much has been put into this project, yet nothing into detailed documentation!

Comment: the `-package` option is not supported, does not work and the article in the link is incorrect in other ways, suggest removing it.

Answer (score 1):

I use the **react-native-rename** npm package.

Install using

```
npm install react-native-rename -g
```

Then from the root of your React Native project execute the following

```
react-native-rename "MyApp" -b com.mycompany.myapp
```

[react-native-rename on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)

Comment: This did work with prior version in android, however using it with 0.71.2 wont work anymore. Already updated the package to it's new version.

Answer (score 0):

If your text editor able to replace a string in all of your project files it is very easy to change package id.

I am using PhpStorm and I just replaced my old.package.id with new.package.id in all of my project files. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

**simply just change your package name in these 4 files**

android => app => src => main => java => com => reactNativeSampleApp => **MainActivity.java** & **MainApplication.java**
android => app => src => main => **AndroidManifest.xml**
android => app => **build.gradle**