# 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-studio, manifest

I have just created an react-native app and building the React Native application giving me The error below.

```
H:\App Data\ejob-app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.ejob-app'.

H:\App Data\ejob-app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in <application> tag must be a valid Java class name.

H:\App Data\ejob-app\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name.
```

And Ended up with the error below..

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'H:\App Data\ejob-app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.ejob.app' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --        
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and 
have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` to check the required configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ejob-app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.ejob-app.MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ejob-app.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please guide me on this, please tell me if i missing something. i am very new to react-native.

Comment: upload codes from AndroidManifest.xml too

Comment: also show us `app/build.gradle`, since it says `error build.gradle line 1 > Plugin with id 'com.ejob.app' not found.`

Comment: You are missing < tag in your manifest please find and fix that.

Comment: also might have to take care about avoiding numbers from package name

Answer (score 14):

Package name should not contain dashes. Rename your package from

> 'com.ejob-app'

to

> 'com.ejob_app'

You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and in my case, the problem was that when I created flutter project, I gave the org name as in.mycompany (observe, "in"). Now, it seems "in" is a keyword in Dart and so, Android Studio uses `in` in the files that it generates. However, that make Gradle unhappy, and causes it to generate message saying name must be a valid Java package name. Quite a conundrum :)

The solution is to search for this string `in`.mycompany in the whole project and change it to in.mycompany in build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml files (there are several of such files, so just search). But leave it as `in` in the kotlin file MainActivity.kt

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solution by @Priyshrm works, I had the same problem, the package name was changed to "'in'.companyname.appname" and this 'in' was creating problem. Just remove '' and solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).