# Renamed react native app, Activity class MainActivity does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

For my app to be accepted on the play store, I have had to rename my app.

I have changed the `applicationId` in `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tcapp" // from
    applicationId "com.rg.tcapp" // to
```

When I run `react-native run-android` I get the error:

> Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.tcapp/com.tcapp.MainActivity} does not exist.

What other files do I need to change to rename my app and get it running?

Comment: Have you also changed all the ``com.tcapp`` references in your manifest? And have you also changed the namespace used in your MainActivity?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio you must set your app name in the strings XML under     <string name="app_name">App Name Here</string>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rename an application, you can use [react-native-rename](https://github.com/junedomingo/react-native-rename#readme) to do it

Answer (score 0):

I've recently changed my package name in react native due to which the entire folder structure needed to be changed in android. react-native-rename didnt help me, but i've followed the steps of the verified answer of the below link, please do check that out, it will help you. Follow all those steps. [Rename android package and application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native)