# Change Package Name React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

How do I create a project in React Native with the package name I want? I already tried

```
react-native init MyApp -package ˜br.com.gabrielgp.MyApp˜
```

and also

```
react-native init MyApp --package=br.com.gabrielgp.MyApp
```

but it does not work, continues `com.MY_APP_NAME`. I also tried using

```
npm install -g react-native-rename
react-native-rename MyApp -b br.com.gabrielgp.MyApp
```

but changed the structure of my project.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a supported feature right now. If you want to make your own package, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native).

Comment: It has told on a github issue. This issue can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12721)