# You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app() - Jest testing

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to test my app using jest but encountered an error "You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app()". Below is my code

```
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  Platform.OS = 'android';
  firebase.initializeApp({//credentials hidden
  });
  const _firestore = firebase.firestore();
  const personStore = new PersonStore(_firestore);
  const app = renderer
    .create(
      <Provider {...personStore}>
        <PersonInfo />
      </Provider>,
    )
    .getInstance();
});
```

What am I missing?
I've tried this solution https://rnfirebase.io/install-android but to no avail
And @react-native-firebase/app is working if I'm not in test mode

Comment: Did you added all gradles and configured in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Try the getting started steps: [Getting Started](https://rnfirebase.io)

The solution you tried is a secondary step. 
Also firebase is segmented in modules, so you should install the required modules separated. if you are going to use the firestore you have to install the module.
[Firestore Module](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage)

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was with mismatch in the package name of the app throughout the project (I started out with a MyApp project and then changed the name but not in all the necessary places).

I then followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37390022/9186580) to rename everything and it started working

Answer (score 0):

Mock the package.

Create a `setup-tests.js` file with content mock:

```
jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/app', jest.fn(() =>
 ({
    firestore: jest.fn(),
    initializeApp: jest.fn(),
    // ... etc
  })

));
```

And add this file to `setupFilesAfterEnv` in `jest.config.ts`

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setup-tests.jsx']
```