# Issue renaming existing expo application

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new to react native and I want to rename the project name and its package name I gone through this

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1946 -- according to this I changed the app.json.

```
Expo {
   name: something 
}
```

[Change package name for Android in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native) - according to this I installed rename package but got below

```
A directory should be created using "react-native init"
```

And I also want to know how can I check my app package name while using expo as it won't have an android/ios directory.

Both are not showing the expected result. please help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Notes Guru",
    "slug": "Notes-Guru",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/logo.jpg",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/logo_mini.png"
    },
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/template.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "icon": "./assets/logo.jpg",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSRemindersUsageDescription": "This app uses the calendar"
      },
      "associatedDomains": [
        "applinks:test.page.link"
      ],
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jk0712.notesguru"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "[notesguru.com][1]",
      "versionCode": 2,
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/logo.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "d7e815f1-ef5f-4834-bd4b-69ad85f633e5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add explanation.