# change react-native package id name

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package

I have created a react-native project with CLI command `npx react-native init myapp`

By running the above command it has created a project for me with the package id `com.myapp`

But I don't want my package id to be `com.myapp` instead I want it to be `in.myapp.myapp123` so is it possible to change the package name to something like this?

The main thing I want to know is dose the package name can start with `in.packagename` instead of `com.packagename`. please help if you know the answer...

Answer (score 0):

To change of the `com.` causes in Error and required for the Appstores. There is more Information here:

[Change package name for Android in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389905/change-package-name-for-android-in-react-native)

and

https://saumya.github.io/ray/articles/72/

Answer (score -1):

you can change myapp123 instead of myapp.
so you can replace myapp to myapp123 in file listed below.

1. app.json
2. package-lock.json
3. package.json
4. android/settings.gradle
5. android/app/BUCK
6. AndroidManifest.xml
7. MainActivity.java
8. MainApplication.java